# `TypeError: get_config() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` while trying to save the model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Please help me with the following. I can't seem to save my model. As you can see I do reference the instance of the `Sequential()` method

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[timePortion,1 ]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=timePortion,
                                 filters=1000, 
                                 strides=1,
                                 use_bias=False,
                                 activation="relu",
                                 kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling))
model.summary()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,
                                activation='relu', 
                                kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8,
                                activation='relu', 
                                kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 
                                kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              loss="mean_squared_error", 
              metrics=["accuracy","mae"])
filepath = "model.h5"
model.fit(inputs,
          labels,
          steps_per_epoch=1,
          epochs=2,
          shuffle=False, 
          verbose=1)
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,
                           filepath, 
                           overwrite=True,
                           include_optimizer=True)
```

I'm having problems saving my model in a Jupyter notebook. The file actually gets created but then I get this error. It's weird cause I am referencing the model instance.

```
TypeError: get_config() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the kernel initializer that cannot be serialized because you haven't instantiated it. To instantiate it add round brackets `()`:

```py
kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling()
```